# What is the Btrfs extended attribute 'm'?

Tags: btrfs

I recently found one of my Virtual Machine images with the extended attribute 'm'. I tried to look it up, but I found no information. Is this an undocumented extended attribute?

```
$ lsattr usb2ubuntu.btrfs.img*
---------------------m usb2ubuntu.btrfs.img
---------------------- usb2ubuntu.btrfs.img.210810_15:02:49.bak
```

Notice the attribute doesn't exist on the backup file.

Comment: Add the output of `lsattr -l` (long names instead abbreviations)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The `chattr` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html) says:

```
   m      A file with the 'm' attribute is excluded from compression
          on file systems that support per-file compression.
```